# Atom on Mac - No Syntax Highlighting for new/open files

Tags: macos, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor, macos-sierra

I have gruvbox theme installed for syntax highlighting theme, but also have tried others with the following effect;

If I open a new file or an existing file, there is no syntax highlighting.  However, if I goto Atom, config and it opens config.cson I see syntax highlighting correctly.  Same as going to Atom in Mac titlebar, then selecting "Init Script..." - syntax highlighting works file.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What language are you using? Bear in mind that Atom automatically detects the language you're using and highlights the syntax accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The core packages installed with Atom only feature syntax highlighting for a limited [collection of languages](https://github.com/atom/language-examples#languages). Presumably, to prevent the mandatory installation of unnecessary packages in accordance with the editors *a la carte* build philosophy.
Consequently, I would suggest searching your installed Atom packages for the language you're trying to use. If you find the language is not already installed, you will most likely be able to install language-support via the following command: `apm install language-<your-language>`